# laravel error 500 (browser) after change of php version

Tags: laravel

Yesterday I had to update the version of PHP 7.4 to 8.0.13.
Since then, when I access my site, I get a 500 (browser) error.
The error occurs on the line:
require __DIR __. '/ .. / vendor / autoload.php';
in the public / index.php file.

Does anyone have (any idea please? please

I have already tried all the basic commands:
php artisan config: clear
php artisan cache: clear
compose dump-autoload
...

delete the vendor directory and recreate it
...

check the rights on the directories

UPDATE 10:13

I just saw in /var/logs/apache2/error.log

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/welrdv/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php on line 2501

UPDATE 10:18

I didn't have it before but I put memory_limit = -1 in /Etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini.

Is this the correct method?

Comment: Are you still getting the error? And also setting unlimited value is not exactly proper, try setting a static value like 512MB or somthing

Comment: It's good to check your stack trace in case there's an infinite loop somewhere e.g. if your error handler is itself erroring and triggering itself. Increasing the memory limit is not something you should need to do due to a PHP version upgrade. It's more likely you missed something in the [PHP 8 migration process](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php)

Answer (score 0):

`memory_limit = -1` is a value PHP understands as *unlimited*. It can use up most of the RAM and even swap to disk. This could be useful only in dev environments to test purposes.

Just increase this value enough: `memory_limit = 128MB`